# How to fix division multiple divisions to top of screen (Parallax scrolling website help)

Tags: html, css, scroll, parallax

I intend to create a parallax scrolling website for a school project.

For my website, I need to fix 4 divisions, which are graphics of screens (etc a laptop screen, a phone screen) to the top of the page and when I scroll past a certain amount of content, te fixed "screen" division will change to the next screen.

It will be kind of similar to the Google Calendar About Us page where content will scroll across the phone screen but now with 4 screens. It was also inspired by ihatetomatoes's Gameboy 25th anniversary page. I'm not sure how to go about doing this though.

I know how to fix a division to the top of the screen but I don't know how to get this fixed division to scroll away when the content reaches a certain amount of pixels to the next fixed div.

Also I would like to ask if it's possible to have a background that also scroll at certain pixels for the whole page as the "screen" graphics will not stretch across the whole screen.

Sorry if this is long-winded, thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a cool school project. You can do the scrolling pictures with css and javascript like this:

CSS:

```
#picDIV/*make a div with all the pictures side by side*/{
overflow-x: auto;
}
#imgId/*The only way i can think of to put images side by side is to asign each one a position like this*/{
position: absolute;
left: /*to the left of your previous pic*/;
}
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
function scroll (){
    $("#picDIV").scrollleft(/*specify in pixles where next image is*/);
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="picDIV"><!--Side by side images--><img class="img" src=""><img class="img" src=""></div>
<button onclick="scroll()">Scroll Left</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As for doing that with your entire page you can do the same thing except use `$("body").scrollTop(/*# of pix*/)`.

Comment: thanks I shall try that. The idea is for 3 layers? The background pictures, the content scroll and the graphic overlay. The background pictures and graphics change togheter but need to only scroll when the content reaches a certain point.

Comment: so say at 1000px, it will scroll from my Intro page to the first set of graphic overlay and picture background. Then when the content scrolls to 10,000 px, the overlay and background will switch to the next set